Can I empty the storage folder when migrating a Craft CMS site?
I am moving a Craft CMS to new webhost and followed this instruction. I read in another Stackoverflow post and also on this page that the /storage folder mainly contains cached, temporary files. Is it safe to empty the whole folder (incl. sub-folder) when migrating a site or is there anything to consider?

The storage folder should be safe to empty out. In a vanilla Craft install, there shouldn't be anything in there that won't be regenerated (i.e. caches, compiled templates, etc), or that your Craft install can't function properly without (i.e. backups or temp files).
One thing to watch out for (and possibly retain) is the storage/rebrand folder. This folder contains your site's login page logo and site icon files (if you have uploaded those), and should probably not be deleted. The rebrand folder is often kept in version control, and other storage sub folders might also be.
TL;DR: Yes, it should be safe, but make sure that none of the storage sub folders being deleted are tracked in git.
